# How to filter for Chinese fonts in Font Book on Sierra?

Tags: macos, font-book

Font Book has Smart Collections, which allows you to filter based on font properties. I created a Smart Collection with the filter "Languages include:"

It works if I enter "French" or "Japanese", but if I use "Chinese", there are no results.

I looked in a Chinese font's properties (e.g. Baoli SC), and it lists "Chinese (Simplified)" under Languages. I tried all of these search terms, but none worked:

```
Chinese
Chinese*
Chinese (Traditional)
Chinese (Simplified) 
Traditional
*Traditional*
Simplified
*Simplified*
```

It seems to me a major oversight/bug that Font Book's Smart Collection filter cannot search for a term that has spaces in it. (Or is there a way to "escape" a space?)

Side note: In Yosemite, some of the Chinese fonts' Language properties have "Chinese, Chinese (Simplified)", so those will show up if you do a Smart Collection for "Chinese", but not "Chinese (Simplified)". In Sierra, however, none of the Chinese fonts' Language properties has "Chinese" alone.

Comment: This is possibly a bug affecting Yosemite that has since been fixed by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Smart Collection on High Sierra for filtering Chinese fonts.
It's an `Any` rule set consisting of three separate `Languages` include tests for: `Chinese`, `Chinese (Simplified)`, and `Chinese (Traditional)`.

[image: Smart Collection Rules]

Answer (score 0):

This is a Sierra bug.  You have to be in 10.11 or 10.13 for Chinese smart collection to work.  Same for some other languages I think.